# AngularJS Loses Selected Item on View Reload (data type of parameter lost)

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, selecteditem

I'm running into an issue in an Angular SPA where a `select` is losing the selected item when a view is reloaded.  The selected item value is correct.  This is a typical search/results scenario, so I must be missing something basic.

The angular module (much condensed here) is set up with ui routes and states, which determine the views and controllers to load, etc.:

```
var DomainApp = angular.module('DomainApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularValidator']);

// add controllers, services, and factories
DomainApp.controller('ProductsController', ProductsController);
DomainApp.service('ProductsService', ProductsService);

var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('productSearch', {
            url: '/products',
            views: {
                "searchView": {
                    templateUrl: '/Templates/products/Search.html',
                    controller: ProductsController
                }
            }
        })
        .state('productResults', {
            url: '/products/Results?categoryID',
            views: {
                "searchView": {
                    templateUrl: '/Templates/products/Search.html',
                    controller: ProductsController
                }
            }
        })
    }
    configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    DomainApp.config(configFunction);
```

The products controller:

```
var ProductsController = function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $location, ProductsService) {
    // data for search operations
    $scope.searchQuery = {
        categoryID: $stateParams.categoryID || 0,
        categories: null
    };

    // init api
    $scope.init = function () {
        var categoryResult = ProductsService.getCategories(0);
        categoryResult.then(function(result) {
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                $scope.searchQuery.categories = result.data.Items;
            } else {
                $scope.status.isError = true;
                $scope.status.errorMessage = result.message;
            }
        });
    }
}

ProductsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$location', 'ProductsService'];
```

The products service:

```
var ProductsService = function ($http, $q) {
    this.getCategories = function (categoryID) {
        var deferredObject = $q.defer();
        var results = {
            isSuccess: true,
            message: '',
            data: null
        }

        $http.get('/api/categories/list/100' + ',' + categoryID).
            success(function (data) {
                results.data = data;
                deferredObject.resolve(results);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                results.isSuccess = false;
                results.message = 'Could not get Category list:';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    results.message = results.message + ' ' + data[i].Message;
                }
                deferredObject.resolve(results);
            });

        return deferredObject.promise;
    };
}

ProductsService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

And the product search template (view):

```
<div class="container-fluid searchbar" data-ng-init="init()">
    <h2>Product Search</h2>
    <div class="row top5">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label for="category">Category:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="40" id="categoryID" ng-model="searchQuery.categoryID" />
            <select class="form-control" name="category" ng-model="searchQuery.categoryID">
                <option value="0">Any</option>
                <option ng-repeat="item in searchQuery.categories" value="{{item.CategoryID}}">{{item.CategoryName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row top15">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="productResults({categoryID: searchQuery.categoryID})">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view, the select values are populated by `data-ng-init="init()"`, and the `input` box and `select` dropdown are tied to the same model item `ng-model="searchQuery.categoryID"`.

What happens when the view is loaded after selecting a category, is that the value is lost, and the selection reverts to "Any".  The text box has the correct selected value.  I verified that the `select` is bound to the model element, as changing the value in the `input` changes the selected item in the `select`.  On reload, I can see the `select` flicker, looks like it has the selected value for a moment then loses it.

**Edit**: In summary, the selected category is only "lost" as the selected item in the `select`.  The selected category value appears correctly in the url, and in the `input` textbox.  This isn't a reference compare issue as the select option values are `item.CategoryID` and not the `item` category object.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can the `select` be detached from the bound value and/or am I setting up the binding wrong?

Incidentally, I also tried `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` to set up the `select`, but in that case changing the value in the `input` had no affect.

Comment: Does the onchange logging show anything relevant?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by onchange logging, but I wired an ng-change and onchange on the select to show an alert.  The former isn't firing, and the latter fires on user selection change (with correct value).

Comment: Could this be due to the "select using  reference compare instead of value compare" ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select + http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/ (fiddle is from the angularjsdoc page, replicated here)

Comment: @Marvin, thanks I am doing a by value compare, I will try a scheme by reference.

Comment: @MarvinSmit Why don't you write it as an answer? Dave, I meant setting a logging function in a onchange listener callback to debug it more easily, but you've found the issue.

Comment: Trying by reference didn't to seem to have any effect, and the select values are scalar (not objects).  Changing the value in the input changes the select, so by value comparison seems to work.

Comment: @Shomz. I don't know if that really is the problem, its just a hunch i got after reading and thinking about this problem. Hence not an answer yet. Only if it turned out to be the issue would i upgrade the comment to answer.

Comment: @Marvin, good check, but I can confirm the by reference isn't the issue here.  In that example fiddle, change to by value (ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options" and related changes), and that works fine.

Comment: Note that you said when `when the view is loaded after selecting a category, is that the value is lost` -- You are going to be calling that ng-init whenever the view is reloaded/DOM is modified (digest cycle fires)

Comment: @cerd, yes, I am expecting to have to call init() on reload to get the category values (unless there is another way for these values to be stored and retrieved).  The selected category is only "lost" as the selected item.  The category value is in the url, the controller has the value, and the input textbox has the value.  Why doesn't the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is actually a [bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/246) in `$stateParams`, where the data type of the integer is lost, and becomes a string.  This issue was supposedly fixed in version 0.2.12 of Angular UI Router, but I'm still seeing the issue in 0.2.13 and have to work around the issue by converting the parameter value back to a number.

The updated products controller with the `Number` function:

```
var ProductsController = function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $location, ProductsService) {
    // data for search operations
    $scope.searchQuery = {
        categoryID: Number($stateParams.categoryID) || 0,
        categories: null
    };

    // init api
    $scope.init = function () {
        var categoryResult = ProductsService.getCategories(0);
        categoryResult.then(function(result) {
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                $scope.searchQuery.categories = result.data.Items;
            } else {
                $scope.status.isError = true;
                $scope.status.errorMessage = result.message;
            }
        });
    }
}

ProductsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$location', 'ProductsService'];
```